# Is Twitter support OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow?

Tags: javascript, authentication, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0

I've been searching through the developer documentation but couldn't found any clue.

Usually there are 2 endpoints provided:

- Authorization endpoint, showing login UI and consent screen and provided authorization code.
- Token endpoint, to exchange authorization code provided by Authorization endpoint into access token.

Anyone know what those 2 endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Looks like they support oauth2 for client credentials grant only (i.e. application with only). Any user flows seem to be oauth 1?

3-legged, etc.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/token.html

Comment: This is correct. User authentication is via OAuth 1.0A. Application-only authentication (which prevents any user-specific functionality being used in the API) uses the client credentials grant OAuth 2.0 flow.